# Rails Unable to Autoload Constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following folder structure:

```
- models/
  - mappings/
    - user.rb
  - mapping.rb
  - service.rb
  - user.rb
  - ...
```

In mappings/user.rb, I have the following:

```
module Mappings
  class User < Mapping

  end
end
```

And mapping.rb is:

```
class Mapping < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

In config/application.rb, I am autoloading the models as follows:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib #{config.root}/app/presenters)
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this `load_missing_constant` error:

```
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:481:in `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant User, expected /vagrant/app/models/mappings/user.rb to define it (LoadError)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure what I'm missing!

UPDATE:

Full trace:

> 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in`
>   const_get' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in
>   `block in constantize' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |  from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in`
>   each' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |  from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in
>   `inject' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in`
>   constantize' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:552:in `get' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:583:in`constantize' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:302:in
>   `get' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:80:in`
>   to' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:75:in
>   `modules' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:92:in`
>   routes' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:159:in
>   `default_used_route' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:69:in`
>   initialize' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:336:in
>   `new' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise.rb:336:in`
>   add_mapping' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:224:in
>   `block in devise_for' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in`
>   each' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |  from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in
>   `devise_for' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from /vagrant/config/routes.rb:93:in`
>   block in ' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:344:in
>   `instance_exec' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:344:in`
>   eval_block' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:322:in
>   `draw' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |  from /vagrant/config/routes.rb:1:in`' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in`block in load' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in`load' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in`each' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |  from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in`reload!' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in`
>   call' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |  from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in
>   `execute' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in`updater' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in
>   `execute_if_updated' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:71:in`
>   block in ' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
>   `instance_exec' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
>   run' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
>   `block in run_initializers' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in`
>   block in tsort_each' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in
>   `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component' 16:53:48
>   jobs.1 |  from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in`
>   each_strongly_connected_component_from' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in
>   `block in each_strongly_connected_component' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in`
>   each' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |  from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in
>   `call' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |  from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in`
>   each_strongly_connected_component' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in
>   `tsort_each' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in`
>   tsort_each' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
>   `run_initializers' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |  from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in`
>   initialize!' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in
>   `public_send' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in`
>   method_missing' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /vagrant/config/environment.rb:8:in `<top (required)>' 16:53:48 jobs.1
>   |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`require' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in`load_dependency' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in`
>   require_environment!' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |  from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:52:in
>   `<top (required)>' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |  from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in`require' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `require_command!' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |   from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:95:in`
>   runner' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |    from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in
>   `run_command!' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |  from
>   /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`
>   ' 16:53:48 jobs.1 |  from bin/rails:8:in `require'
>   16:53:48 jobs.1 |     from bin/rails:8:in`'

So it looks like the issue is because I have to classes named `User`, even though one is namespaced inside a Module.

Comment: It seems you are trying to call  `User` rather than `Mappings::User` - it is however pretty weird as your `mappings` folder is not directly in the autoload path. Anything intersting in the initalizers?

Comment: I am getting this error when starting the rails server, so I'm not actually getting to the point of calling `Mappings::User`. I also tried adding `    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', 'mappings','{**}')]` but no success.

Comment: in that case couple of things you might try. Firstly, add `require: false`next to a FactoryGirl gem in you Gemfile. Requiring it in a development causes all the models to be loaded on startup (factories are loaded). You should be able to load the console then. Tr to load your models then and find out which is raising this error. Check it for any associations with Mappings::User models which are called `:users` - most likely you will need to add `class_name: 'Mappings::User'` to those.

Comment: Could you also get a full trace on this error? It will help identify the root cause.

Comment: Added the trace. It looks like the issue is because I have two models named `User` despite the fact that one is namespaced under `Mappings`. I figure it will be best to just rename it to `UserMapping`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're defining the `User` class within the `Mapping` module. It looks at `user.rb`, doesn't see the `User` class and errors out. Try removing the module call and see if that works.

Edit: In response to the comment, perhaps you should make that explicit in the class name then. `Mappings::User`. You'll likely need to inherit it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment. I would like to namespace the User class because I have another User class in the `models/` directory. I would like to be able to access this User model by `Mappings::User`